# is the UAC Elevation icon supposed to exist on wix boostrapper uninstall Button?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, uninstallation, uac, bootstrapper

Is the UAC elevation icon supposed to be visible on the Wix Standard Bootstrapper **Uninstall** button?

The install button always has the icon for me.

[image]

but not the uninstall button.

[image]

This is on a double click of the exe.

thanks!

Comment: I would assume this is a bug in the default Burn Bootstrapper application. I am not really that familiar with this code-base, but I suppose you can look yourself under: https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix3/tree/develop/src/ext/BalExtension - I think I have seen this issue described before on this site. Maybe do a quick search (sorry no time right now).

Comment: @SteinÅsmul I've done a search, and have not found it. It's possible I've missed it. I greatly appreciate your time on this.

Comment: @SteinÅsmul any thoughts?